# Campaign Monitor API - Custom Form

Tags: php, forms, campaign-monitor

Following on from Campaign Monitors API change I cannot find any documentation to create a custom subscribe form which collects a users email address and automatically adds it to a specific subscriber list.

There is documentation for their API, which I have got working, but nothing I can find about integrating this into a form.

This is based on: https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-php

```
    <?php

    require_once 'cmp/csrest_subscribers.php';

    $auth = array(
        'api_key' => 'Your API key'
    );
    $wrap = new CS_REST_Subscribers( 'Your list ID', $auth );

    $result = $wrap->add( array(
        'EmailAddress' => 'Subscriber email',
        'Name' => 'Subscriber name',
        'CustomFields' => array(
            array(
                'Key' => 'Field 1 Key',
                'Value' => 'Field Value'
            ),
            array(
                'Key' => 'Field 2 Key',
                'Value' => 'Field Value'
            ),
            array(
                'Key' => 'Multi Option Field 1',
                'Value' => 'Option 1'
            ),
            array(
                'Key' => 'Multi Option Field 1',
                'Value' => 'Option 2'
            )
        ),
        'ConsentToTrack' => 'yes',
        'Resubscribe' => true
    ) );

    ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this question is better asked over at the repo or Campaign Monitor's support? It's very specific to the package and requires us to know all the ins and outs of it.

Comment: OK the support team have said...you'd need to submit the form data to your own endpoint, which then posts to our API via this call https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/subscribers/#adding-a-subscriber - to add the subscriber to their list.